# Magento 2 Block Does not show

Tags: magento2, php

I am new with Magento, I found that it's realy hard to do even for doing trivial thing.

I just try to follow this article https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html but the block seems does not loaded.

**Here is my routes.xml**

[image]

**Here is my controller**

[image]

**Here is my layout**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Display" name="helloworld_display" template="Mageplaza_HelloWorld::sayhello.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**Here is my phtml**

[image]

**This is my browser view**

[image]

I have tried this in my Block but nothing was happened.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento layout use id route's id attribute to detect layout handler. 
So, you should change your layout file name to **helloworld_home_index_display.xml**

Comment: You are right mate, thank you, you save my day!